# Gradle - Do adding the same dependency to different modules increase build time?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-dependencies

If I have **moduleA** and **moduleB**, which both implement `dependencyA` and `dependencyB`.  Will declaring both dependencies increase load time for moduleB if moduleA was already compiled?

For more information, a project has the following problem and I want to know if I should refactor it for a decent build time gain:

The project uses several dependencies across several modules, in order to clean up code, the project added a **Dependencies.kt** file where all versions of dependencies are added, and we also added "groups", so that for example all the Firebase dependencies are under a single object that implements the required libs.

```
fun DependencyHandler.firebase() {
    implementation(Dependencies.Firebase.core)
    implementation(Dependencies.Firebase.cloudMessaging)
    implementation(Dependencies.Firebase.remoteConfig)
    implementation(Dependencies.Firebase.analytics)
    implementation(Dependencies.Firebase.crashlytics)
}
```

so the build.gradle.kts file would look something as:

```
dependencies {
    app()
    design()
    rx()
    network()
    firebase()
}
```

Now, not all modules require *firebase cloud messaging*, but they will still call the `firebase()` dependency in order to import the group and keep things clean.

I want to know if the module will increase considerably the configuration and build time by adding libs that are not really required to the module, if those libs were already loaded for another module.

Comment: In isolation, yes it would make building slower, but probably not significantly. I'd be more concerned about the project artifacts being larger, and as they have a wider footprint being more vulnerable to conflicts or security issues. Maybe you want to expose dependencies to other subprojects using `api(...)` instead? But there are many other factors - I recommend you do whatever is most convenient.

Comment: artifacts shouldn't be larger because dependencies are not transitive.